# How to split a string by a certain string?

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split a string by a character sequence, not by a single character. I have this:

```java
String m = "Alcides&|&ola&|&Alcides";
String[] split = m.split("&|&");
System.out.println(split[0] + split[1] + split[2]);
```

My goal is to have in `split[0] -> Alcides` and in `split[1] -> ola` and in `split[2] -> Alcides`.

But instead the result of the `System.out.println` is:

```
Alcides|ola|
```

Answer (score 4):

[`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) expects a regex. That means you have to escape the `|` (which is a [logical operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum))

```
String[] split = m.split("&\\|&");
```

Answer (score 3):

`split` takes string representing *regex* (regular expression).

If you don't know if some character or sequence may be considered as special/meta for regex (like in your case `|` which represents `OR` operator, or maybe something like `\s` which represents all whitespaces) you can use `Pattern.quote(yourString)` to generate regex which represents only `yourString`.

So in your case you can use

```
String[] split = m.split(Pattern.quote("&|&"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` should be escaped because it is used as OR in regular expression:

```java
String m = "Alcides&|&ola&|&Alcides";
String[] split = m.split("&\\|&");
System.out.printf("%s  %s  %s%n", split[0], split[1], split[2] ); // Alcides  ola  Alcides
```

Answer (score 0):

Method [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a *string regex* as a parameter, where [*vertical bar*](https://unicode-table.com/en/007C/) character is interpreted as *boolean "or"*. If you don't want to deal with this, you can first [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) these sequences: `&|&` - with something *less markedly*, for example [*triple vertical bar delimiter*](https://unicode-table.com/en/2980/), and then split the string around these delimiters:

```java
String m = "Alcides&|&ola&|&Alcides";
String[] split = m.replace("&|&", "\u2980").split("\u2980");
System.out.println(split[0] + " " + split[1] + " " + split[2]);
// Alcides ola Alcides
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to remove sequence of two elements from array or list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65689147/14940971)</sup>